# Can't call a function in a class returning a char

Tags: c++, arrays, function, char, call

There is an error saying "expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type" when I'm trying to call `st.top()`

```
string infixToPostfix(string hasil)
{
    Stack st;
    string postfix = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < hasil.length(); i++)
    {
        if (hasil[i] == ' ')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (isOperator(hasil[i]))
        {
            while (st.isEmpty() && hasHigherPrecedence(st.top(), hasil[i])) // the error is here
            {
                postfix = postfix + st.top(); // and here
            }

        }
    }
}


class Stack {

    public:
    int top = -1;
    char array[MAX];

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if (top == -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    bool isFull()
    {
        if (top == (MAX-1))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        } 
    }

    void push(char masuk)
    {

        if (isFull())
        {
            cout << "Expresi yang anda masukkan telah melebihi stack" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            top++;
            array[top] = masuk;
        }
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            {
                cout << "Stack sudah kosong!" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                top--;
            }
    }

    char top()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            cout << "Stack kosong" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            return array[top];
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Try just `st.top` because `top` is not a function but a data member.

Comment: You have *two* members named `top`. When you use `top` which one do you really mean? I suggest you rename one of them. *And* make the member variables `private` (which will solve your current errors, but not another problem).

Comment: `while (st.isEmpty() && hasHigherPrecedence(st.top(), hasil[i]))` calls `st.top()` while st.isEmpty. it will make an other error for `char top()` but not return anything.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that solved the problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have both a public member variable *and* a public function called `top`. You should rename one of them.

You should also seriously consider making the variable (and, indeed, all variables) `private` since, otherwise, forces outside your class are free to fiddle with its internals in a way that you won't enjoy.

The whole point of encapsulation is hiding this sort of stuff from the outside world so that your class has a limited number of things it presents. For example, with a public variable, I could just do:

```
st.m_top = -2; // Assumes you've renamed it to distinguish from top().
```

and sit back and enjoy the fireworks :-)